# md5 hex to binary in python

Tags: python, binary, hex, md5

i read many answers about converting hex to binary in SO.  I tried to implement it with md5:

```
import hashlib

c = hashlib.md5("123hello123".encode('ascii'))
print(c.hexdigest())
for _hex in c.hexdigest():
    _hex = int(_hex, 16)
    print(bin(_hex)[2:], end="")
```

i get the output:

> b303fa684382db471658016690101792
>   1011110111111101011010001001110001011011011100111111010110000111011010010101111100110

where as when i convert in an online converter i get:

> 10110011000000111111101001101000010000111000001011011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

what is the right answer?  how should i correct my program?

Comment: What online converter are you using?

Comment: You need to pad each hex digit's binary representation to 4 characters.

Comment: _Both_ of these results look wrong. The one you got from the converter translates to `b303fa684382d8000000000000000000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bin` function does not include leading zeros, while each hex character always represents 4 binary digits. `bin(_hex)[2:].rjust(4,"0")` will work.

Comment: While you're at it, you may as well skip the loop entirely and call `bin` on the entire hex digest just once: `print(bin(int(c.hexdigest(), 16))[2:].rjust(128, "0"))`

Comment: @Kevin that is worth turning into a separate answer.